# Compiling C code using TextMate

Tags: c, makefile, textmate

Suppose you have 3 files in your C project

```
 - a.c
 - a.h // Header for a.c
 - b.c
```

`Apple-R` fails to link files properly, `ld` error comes up. `(ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64)`

[image]

**Running `gcc` manually on a command line works fine `gcc -o executable a.c b.c`**

Can one redefine what `Apple-R` does or should a `makefile` need to be created? Can one link `Apple-R` to `make file?`

Comment: What error did you get?  What's `Apple-R`?

Comment: I got `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`. Linkage does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Make bundle enabled, you should be able to do `Command-B` to build the project with the current Makefile. In any case, you should probably use a Makefile instead of relying on TextMate's "Run" command, which doesn't know about dependencies and whatnot.

Comment: What you always use Make no matter how small the project is?

Comment: It kinda sucks, but how else can TextMate know how to build these files? I generally use a Makefile for all my compiled projects.